# Mapping Select of one list over a second list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a large multi column data file, but for this question it can simplified as follows:

```
data = {{"a", 2000}, {"a", 2010}, {"b", 1999}, {"b", 2004}, {"b", 
2006}, {"c", 2012}, {"c", 2014}};
```

I then have a list of items for which I want to extract the year value from data, e.g:

```
selectedList = {"b", "c"};
```

I can do it by using Select[] and then iterating through the selectedList:

```
Table[
        Select[data, #[[1]] == selectedList[[i]] &][[All, 2]],

       {i, 1, Length[selectedList]}  ]
```

However I want to use Map, which should be faster than Table. I can do this:

```
func[dat_, x_] := Select[dat, #[[1]] == x &][[All, 2]]
```

and then :

```
func[data, #] & /@ selectedList
```

I am looking for a more elegant way to do this in one step, preferably mapping Select directly  onto selectedList

Answer (score 6):

```
Cases[data, {#, x_} :> x] & /@ selectedList
```

Comment: +1, but I would usually wrap that in `Block[{x}, ... ]` just in case `x` is defined somewhere else.  It spoils the brevity though.

Comment: This is elegant indeed, but my real datafile is from excel and is a multi column file with the date in column 10 - this will work :-) `Cases[data,{#,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,x_,___}:>x] & /@ selectedList`

Comment: Maybe something like `Cases[data22, {#, __, x_, _} :> x] & /@ {"b", "c"}` would work?

Comment: @Chris That is unnecessary: `x` is already localized by `RuleDelayed` (`:>`).

Comment: Good catch Mr.Wizard. I never realised that - only with RuleDelayed.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Map and Cases:

```
data = {{"a", 2000}, {"a", 2010}, {"b", 1999}, {"b", 2004},
   {"b", 2006}, {"c", 2012}, {"c", 2014}};
selectedList = {"b", "c"};

Map[Part[Cases[data, {#, _}], All, 2] &, selectedList]
```

{{1999, 2004, 2006}, {2012, 2014}}

However, if you really want to use Select you can do it as follows.  Function is used to avoid confusing the anonymous slots.  I have built up the function gradually to illustrate:-

```
Select[data, First[#] == "b" &] (* Basic start *)
```

{{"b", 1999}, {"b", 2004}, {"b", 2006}}

```
Select[data, Function[x, First[x] == "b"]] (* Implement with Function *)
```

{{"b", 1999}, {"b", 2004}, {"b", 2006}}

```
Part[Select[data, Function[x, First[x] == "b"]], All, 2]
```

{1999, 2004, 2006}

```
Map[Part[Select[data,
    Function[x, First[x] == #]], All, 2] &, selectedList]
```

{{1999, 2004, 2006}, {2012, 2014}}

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for Cases or Select, but not Table :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using `Position` :

```
Map[Function[x, data[[Position[data, x][[All, 1]], 2]]], selectedList]

(* {{1999, 2004, 2006}, {2012, 2014}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

For variation here is another one based on select:

```
Last[#\[Transpose]] & /@ (Select[data, Function[x, First[x] == #1]] & ) 
/@ selectedList
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ data, selectedList][[2, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{1999, 2004, 2006}, {2012, 2014}}
> ```

This is easy to adapt to other structures, e.g. column ten:  `Sow[#10, #]`

On large data sets and with a long `selectedList` this will be faster than `Cases` because the data is not rescanned for every selection element.

Example:

```
data = {RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 50000], 
        RandomInteger[100000, 50000]}\[Transpose];

selectedList = RandomSample @ CharacterRange["a", "z"];

Reap[Sow[#2, #] & @@@ data, selectedList][[2, All, 1]]; //AbsoluteTiming

Cases[data, {#, x_} :> x] & /@ selectedList;            //AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0210012, Null}
>
> {0.1010057, Null}
> ```